# Texture looks distorted

Tags: texturing, uv

Could anyone please tell me how I can fix the distortion I'm getting on the texture?

[image: Here is the glitch]

[image]

Comment: Try to remake UVs and re organize. could recalculate normal maybe word or change to cubic uv mode. if not work you can send the file to me try to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more subdivisions on the arch. UVs determine the placement of textures on the geometry. If the image has to be somehow scaled or shifted then large faces with no subdivisions tend to create errors. As a general rule try to avoid ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices) and distrubute the geometry at regular intervals.

Comment: Thanks, just making them all quad made the glitch go away.